# Как следует перевести термин "Meta"?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Как мы планируем перевести термин "meta"?

- Стоит ли оставить как есть?
- Или перевести как «Мета»?
- Если кириллица, то склоняется или нет?
- Прописная/строчная буква?

Comment: А нет ли возможности просто перенести? `Stack Overflow Meta на русском`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

Вариант склоняемой «Меты» с прописной буквы (участвовать в Мете, сообщение на Мету).

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- Вариант несклоняемого «Мета» с прописной буквы (участвовать в Мета, сообщение на Мета).
- Вариант склоняемой «Меты» с прописной буквы (участвовать на Мете, сообщение на Мету). Мета - форум, значит участвовать «на форуме», «на Мете».
- Вариант meta (участвовать в meta, сообщение на meta).
- Вариант несклоняемого «мета» (участвовать в мета, сообщение на мета).
- Вариант склоняемой «меты» (участвовать в мете, сообщение на мету).
- Вариант склоняемой «меты» (участвовать на мете, сообщение на мету). Мета - форум, значит участвовать «на форуме», «на мете».
- Вариант Meta (участвовать в Meta, сообщение на Meta).